# How to get UITextView to anchor to the right of UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

I have UITextView that I want to anchor to the right of my UICollectionViewCell. I apply the following constraint: `textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true`
But it DOES NOT anchor all the way to the right. I then apply the following constraint but this time:  `textView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor).isActive = true` and it DOES anchor all the way to the left. Why might this be?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoQOp.jpg

Here is my ChatMessageCell.

```
import UIKit

class ChatMessageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    let textView: UITextView = {
        let tv = UITextView()
        tv.text = "Some Text"
        tv.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        tv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tv
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        addSubview(textView)

        textView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you remove 


```textView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true```


Could it be that they are 2 conflicting constraints?

Add a background colour to the textview and upload that to get a better view of what the textview size is.

Comment: When working with alignments its always best to add a background color to your view, so you can better understand where each of the views is placed on the screen. In your case, if you add a background color to your TextView you may find that the TextView is correctly aligned to the right, but the text within the TextView is left aligned. Try setting the text alignment to right as textView.textAlignment = .right

Answer (score 0):

Your textView would be left-aligned. If you want your text view to remain with a width of 200 and appear to sit on the right you need to add: `textView.textAlignment = .right`

Also, I belive it's best to use leading and trailing constraints